# Fetch records that are non zero after the decimal point in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, types, postgresql-8.4

I have a table with an amount field of type **Numeric**. It contains different amount values. For example

```
5.00
7.13
8.86
6.00
1.00
```

... etc.

I've to fetch only those records that are nonzero after the decimal point.
ie, fetch only the records corresponding to the amounts

```
7.13
8.86
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### `numeric` is exact!

Unlike claimed by another answer, **`numeric` is [not a floating-point type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-FLOAT)**, but an [**arbitrary precision type**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL) as defined by the SQL standard. Storage is *exact*. I quote the manual:

> The type numeric can store numbers with a very large number of digits
> and perform calculations exactly. It is especially recommended for
> storing monetary amounts and other quantities where exactness is required.

#### Answer

The natural candidate for your question is the function [**`trunc()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html). It truncates *toward zero* - basically keeping the integer part while discarding the rest. Fastest in a quick test, but the difference is insubstantial among the top contenders.

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE amount <> trunc(amount);
```

`floor()` truncates to the next lower integer, which makes a difference with negative numbers:

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE amount <> floor(amount);
```

If your numbers fit into [`integer` / `bigint`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html) you can also just cast:

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE amount <> amount::bigint;
```

This *rounds* to full numbers, unlike the above.

#### Test

Tested with PostgreSQL 9.1.7. Temporary table with 10k `numeric` numbers with two fractional digits, around 1% have `.00`.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE t(amount) AS
SELECT round((random() * generate_series (1,10000))::numeric, 2);
```

Correct result in my case: 9890 rows. Best time from 10 runs with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`.

Erwin 1

```
SELECT count(*) FROM t WHERE amount <> trunc(amount)          -- 43.129 ms
```

[mvp 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15241165/939860) / [qqx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15240776/939860)

```
SELECT count(*) FROM t WHERE amount != round(amount)          -- 43.406 ms
```

Erwin 3

```
SELECT count(*) FROM t WHERE amount <> amount::int            -- 43.668 ms
```

[mvp 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15241165/939860)

```
SELECT count(*) FROM t WHERE round(amount,2) != round(amount) -- 44.144 ms
```

Erwin 4

```
SELECT count(*) FROM t WHERE amount <> amount::bigint         -- 44.149 ms
```

Erwin 2

```
SELECT count(*) FROM t WHERE amount <> floor(amount)          -- 44.918 ms
```

[Nandakumar V](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15241572/939860)

```
SELECT count(*) FROM t WHERE amount - floor(amount) > .00     -- 46.640 ms
```

Mostly still true in **Postgres 12** (except everything's > 10x faster now). Test with 100k rows instead of 10k:

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=71299c768248046fbaab9f89f168d04e)*

Comment: `random()` **cannot** generate value of `1./3*3`, which CAN be stored in `NUMERIC` field, and it is NOT equal to `1`

Comment: @mvp: A `numeric` field **cannot** hold the *exact* value `1.0 / 3` to begin with. No existing type can. You are discussing a case that is interesting in itself, but not applicable to the question - as I understand it.

Comment: Over 10^9 iterations of this code: `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, VERBOSE) SELECT j, TRUNC((RANDOM() * 5)) AS x FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1, 1000000000) AS j;`, and also for `FLOOR((RANDOM...`, the FLOOR() function was 137ms faster (181996.462 ms (03:01.996) vs.  182132.736 ms (03:02.133) - well within any possible error margins.  PostgreSQL 14.2, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit - home laptop with nothing else running. Just an FYI!

Answer (score 3):

This will work:

```
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE round(amount,2) != round(amount)
```

And no, you **cannot directly compare floating numbers** - below code DOES NOT work ([SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/d4637/1) as proof):

```
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE amount != round(amount)
```

If `amount` = `1./3 * 3`, it looks like it is `1`, but it is NOT - comparison will fail.

Comment: `numeric` is *not* a floating point number. Thus your "proof" does not apply.

Comment: `NUMERIC` is the type used in question. My example also uses `NUMERIC` field, which was calculated as `1./3*3` - this IS possible to happen in real code. However, your example using `random()` CANNOT generate that corner case - it cannot generate NUMERIC value that is equal to `1./3*3`

Answer (score 3):

Will this help

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE amount - floor(amount) >  .00`

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE amount != round(amount);
```