# Group by floating date range

Tags: sql, postgresql, grouping, window-functions, group-by

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.2.
I have table containing time of some devices getting out of service.

```
+----------+----------+---------------------+
| event_id |  device  |         time        |
+----------+----------+---------------------+
|        1 | Switch4  | 2013-09-01 00:01:00 |
|        2 | Switch1  | 2013-09-01 00:02:30 |
|        3 | Switch10 | 2013-09-01 00:02:40 |
|        4 | Switch51 | 2013-09-01 03:05:00 |
|        5 | Switch49 | 2013-09-02 13:00:00 |
|        6 | Switch28 | 2013-09-02 13:01:00 |
|        7 | Switch9  | 2013-09-02 13:02:00 |
+----------+----------+---------------------+
```

I want the rows to be grouped by +/-3 minutes' time difference, like that:

```
+----------+----------+---------------------+--------+
| event_id |  device  |         time        |  group |
+----------+----------+---------------------+--------+
|        1 | Switch4  | 2013-09-01 00:01:00 |      1 |
|        2 | Switch1  | 2013-09-01 00:02:30 |      1 |
|        3 | Switch10 | 2013-09-01 00:02:40 |      1 |
|        4 | Switch51 | 2013-09-01 03:05:00 |      2 |
|        5 | Switch49 | 2013-09-02 13:00:00 |      3 |
|        6 | Switch28 | 2013-09-02 13:01:00 |      3 |
|        7 | Switch9  | 2013-09-02 13:02:00 |      3 |
+----------+----------+---------------------+--------+
```

I tried to make it using window function, but in clause

> [ RANGE | ROWS ] BETWEEN frame_start AND frame_end,
>   where frame_start and frame_end can be one of
>   UNBOUNDED PRECEDING value PRECEDING CURRENT ROW value FOLLOWING
>   UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING,
>
> value must be an integer expression not containing any variables,
>   aggregate functions, or window functions

So, considering this, I'm not able to indicate the time interval. Now I doubt that window function can resolve my problem. Could you help me?

Comment: To clarify question, if you have row with time = '00:03:40' in the above example, will it have group number 2 and other groups shift by +1? Trying to understand what do you mean by +/-3 minutes difference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/25dfc/7)

```
select
    event_id, device, ts,
    floor(extract(epoch from ts) / 180) as group
from t
order by ts
```

It is possible to make the group number a sequence starting at 1 using a window function but it is a not small cost that I don't know if is necessary. This is it

```
select
    event_id, device, ts,
    dense_rank() over(order by "group") as group
from (
    select
        event_id, device, ts,
        floor(extract(epoch from ts) / 180) as group
    from t
) s
order by ts
```

`time` is a reserved word. Pick another one as the column name.

Comment: Nice and simple. I'll suggest a slight improvement.

Answer (score 1):

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/25dfc/4)

```
with u as (
select 
   *,
   extract(epoch from ts - lag(ts) over(order by ts))/ 60 > 180 or lag(ts) over(order by ts) is null as test
from
   t
   )

   select *, sum(test::int) over(order by ts) from u
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just a slight improvement over [@Clodoaldo's basically good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18784121/939860).

To get sequential group numbers:

```sql
SELECT event_id, device, ts
     , dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY trunc(extract(epoch from ts) / 180)) AS grp
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY ts;
```

- Using `ts` instead of the (partly) reserved word `time` is good advice. So don't use the [reserved word](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html) `group` either. Using `grp` instead.
- Sequential numbers can be had without subquery.
- Use `trunc()` instead of `floor()`. Both are good, `trunc()` is [slightly faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15284333/939860).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.depesz.com/2010/09/12/how-to-group-messages-into-chats/

should use windowing. it is a example from textbook

```
with
  xinterval( val ) as ( select 2 ),
  data( id, t ) as 
  (
    values  

      ( 1000, 1 ),
      ( 1001, 2 ),
      ( 1002, 3 ),

      ( 1000, 7 ),
      ( 1003, 8 )

  ),  
  x( id, t, tx ) as
  (
    select id, t,
      case (t - lag(t) over (order by t)) > xinterval.val
        when true then t when null then t
      end
    from data natural join xinterval
  ),
  xx( id, t, t2 ) as
  (
    select id, t, max(tx) over (order by t) from x
  )
select id, t, text( min(t) over w ) || '-' || text( max(t) over w ) as xperiod
from xx
window w as ( partition by t2 )
order by t
```

Comment: Could add some part of the links in case the link is gone some day.

Answer (score 0):

Make function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.date_round (
  base_date timestamp,
  round_interval interval
)
RETURNS TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE AS
$body$
DECLARE
   res TIMESTAMP;
BEGIN   
    res := TIMESTAMP 'epoch' + (EXTRACT(epoch FROM $1)::INTEGER + EXTRACT(epoch FROM $2)::INTEGER / 2)
                / EXTRACT(epoch FROM $2)::INTEGER * EXTRACT(epoch FROM $2)::INTEGER * INTERVAL '1 second';            
    IF (base_date > res ) THEN
        res := res + $2;
    END IF;
    RETURN res;
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
STABLE
CALLED ON NULL INPUT
SECURITY INVOKER
COST 100;
```

And group by this function result

```
SELECT t.* FROM (SELECT p.oper_date, date_round(p.oper_date, '5 minutes') as grp FROM test p) t GROUP BY t.grp
```

This easy :)