# SQL Add a user created results row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
num.description,
(num.new_driver_form/denom.form_sent_to) as conversion
FROM
(SELECT
'Common' as description,
count(DISTINCT u1.user_id) as new_driver_form
FROM   
user_tags u1
JOIN   
user_tags u2 USING (user_id)
WHERE  
u1.name = 'sentForm'
AND    
u2.name = 'recForm')num
JOIN
(SELECT
'Common' as description,
count(DISTINCT user_id) as form_sent_to
FROM 
user_tags
WHERE
name = 'sentForm')denom
ON num.description = denom.description
```

I am receiving an error that "failed to find conversion function from unknown to text", but am not sure what that means.

Comment: where is the description coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an explicit [**type cast**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS) to avoid the error. `'Common'` is just a string literal and Postgres wants you to provide the type it should be cast to.

You will also want to cast the [`bigint`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html) number in `num.new_driver_form` ([`count()` returns `bigint`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html)) to [`numeric`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240652/fetch-records-that-are-non-zero-after-the-decimal-point-in-postgresql/15284333#15284333) (or a lossy floating point type) to get a meaningful result from your divison. You will then be interested in the [`round()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-FUNC-TABLE) function.

```
SELECT num.description
     ,(num.new_driver_form::numeric / denom.form_sent_to) AS conversion
FROM  (
   SELECT 'Common'::text AS description
         ,count(DISTINCT u1.user_id) AS new_driver_form
   FROM   user_tags u1
   JOIN   user_tags u2 USING (user_id)
   WHERE  u1.name = 'sentForm'
   AND    u2.name = 'recForm'
   ) num
JOIN   (
   SELECT 'Common'::text AS description
         ,count(DISTINCT user_id) AS form_sent_to
   FROM   user_tags
   WHERE  name = 'sentForm'
   ) denom ON num.description = denom.description
```

Of course, your `JOIN` doesn't make a lot of sense to begin with, since the second subquery computes a single row and the JOIN condition is always `TRUE`. Can be simplified to:

```
SELECT num.description
     ,(num.new_driver_form::numeric / denom.form_sent_to) AS conversion
FROM  (
   SELECT 'Common'::text AS description
         ,count(DISTINCT u1.user_id) AS new_driver_form
   FROM   user_tags u1
   JOIN   user_tags u2 USING (user_id)
   WHERE  u1.name = 'sentForm'
   AND    u2.name = 'recForm'
   ) num
JOIN   (
   SELECT count(DISTINCT user_id) AS form_sent_to
   FROM   user_tags
   WHERE  name = 'sentForm'
   ) denom ON TRUE
```

Or just use a subquery:

```
SELECT 'Common'::text AS description
      ,(count(DISTINCT u1.user_id)::numeric
       / (SELECT count(DISTINCT user_id)
          FROM   user_tags
          WHERE  name = 'sentForm')) AS conversion
FROM   user_tags u1
JOIN   user_tags u2 USING (user_id)
WHERE  u1.name = 'sentForm'
AND    u2.name = 'recForm'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the easy way

```
SELECT
  'cohort' as description,
  count(DISTINCT u1.user_id) as new_driver_form,
  x.field as field
FROM user_tags u1
JOIN user_tags u2 USING (user_id)
JOIN anothertable X ON x.blah = u1.blah
WHERE  
  u1.name = 'sentForm'
  AND    
  u2.name = 'recForm'
```

If the string is comming from one of the tables something like this would work:

```
SELECT
  <replace with field name> as description,
  count(DISTINCT u1.user_id) as new_driver_form,
  x.field as field
FROM user_tags u1
JOIN user_tags u2 USING (user_id)
JOIN anothertable X ON x.blah = u1.blah
WHERE  
  u1.name = 'sentForm'
  AND    
  u2.name = 'recForm'
```

Comment: i know this is a follow on question, but i did that and tried to join on another query that I also add 'cohort' as description to as well. Is that not possible?

Comment: I am creating the "description" in both tables, and the error is that it "failed to find conversion function from unknown to text"

Comment: @Stuave - You will have to post the sql, I've no idea why that error