# SQL: How to select only rows with non-zero in 'cents' portions of money field?

Tags: sql

My donation table looks like this:

```
id      int
donation  smallmoney
... other columns ...
```

I wish to run a report selecting ONLY rows where the donation amount has a non-zero in the 'cents' portion of the field. For example, if a row had a donation of 12.66, then I would want to select that row. But if the row had a donation of 12.60, then I would skip that row.

Is such a query even possible? I've been googling with no luck.

Thanks experts!

Comment: Related, but not duplicate (unless you're using PostgreSQL, in which case, it's a dupe):  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240652/fetch-records-that-are-non-zero-after-the-decimal-point-in-postgresql

Answer (score 5):

You could also use the modulus operator.

```
select * from table 
where (donation * 100.00) % 100 != 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a fairly simply way:

```
select t.*
from table t
where donation <> cast(donation as int)
```

This casts the donation to an integer, which removes the cents.  If the values are equal, then there were no cents on the original donation.  If they are unequal, then there is something in the cents field.

EDIT:

The question has changed since I answered it.  The above is the simplest for all the cents being zero.  It is easily modified for the final digit:

```
select t.*
from table t
where donation * 10  <> cast(donation * 10 as int)
```

Comment: How would that perform the check for the non-zero cents?

Comment: `selecting ONLY rows where the donation amount has a non-zero in the 'cents' portion of the field.`  I think you've got that backwards, should be `!=` instead of `=`.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables . . .  I did read the question backwards.  I thought it wanted the donations with no cents.

Comment: wouldn't this also return 12.60? I think op only wants rows where the "single" cents are not 0

Comment: will need to multiply donation by 10 at both sides of the <>