# Get floating point numbers from a list

Tags: mysql, sql, floating-point

I am working with a table having `amount` field of type `DECIMAL(5,2)`. The values in the column are

```
id  amount
1   9.00
2   1.83
3   7.01
4   8.00
5   99.85
```

I have to get the columns with only that have nonzero after decimal.

From the above list i should get

```
id  amount
2   1.83
3   7.01
5   99.85
```

How should i write the query to get the result?

I am using MySql 5.6.

Comment: after some searching through SO i found another post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240652/fetch-records-that-are-non-zero-after-the-decimal-point-in-postgresql  even though its for postgres, I think the same can be applied here too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess:

```
SELECT * 
from tblname 
where amount=FLOOR(amount)
```

Comment: it should be `amount != FLOOR(amount)`