# How to Select Only Real Number Data in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to show only real number with SQL Select ?

As example the data in table appear like :

```
Price

100000

10.0022

99980

0.0005

1.5

25000

0

20.5
```

The price data type is number.

I try SQL query like this but fail :

```
SELECT price FROM price_table WHERE price LIKE '%.%';
```

The query return error :

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: numeric ~~ unknown
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fetch records that are non zero after the decimal point in PostgreSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240652/fetch-records-that-are-non-zero-after-the-decimal-point-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`LIKE` is for strings, not for numbers. If you want to find those that do have decimal digits, compare them to their integer value:

```
select *
from price_table
where price::int <> price;
```

To be able to use `LIKE` you need to first convert the number to a string:

```
select *
from price_table
where price::text like '%.%';
```

Comment: Great answer! Thanks